# How do I remove default behavior of img element?

Tags: html, css

[image: img of the problem]

How you can see in the image, I have a little space between a cactus `img` and red line, why does this happen?

I need a 16px of space between both elements, if I just add this in CSS, the space will be 16px + this default space, and I don't want this.

Can anyone help me please?

I've tried set the bottom margin of `img` to 0 but nothing happens.

Comment: Using `img { display: block }` should take care of the extra space below. An `img` is default `display: inline`, causing the space by default.